# Is there any available explanation for why 'crooked' is pronounced as 'krʊk/ɪd/' not 'krʊk/d/?

Tags: pronunciation

Why is 'crooked' pronounced /'krʊk.**ɪd**/ and not /krʊk/d/?
Is there any available explanation for why 'crooked' is pronounced as /'krʊk.ɪd/' not /krʊk/d/?
Or is it just one of the exceptions for '-ed' ending words and it is what it is?

Comment: That would have to be /kt/ rather than /kd/, since /k/ is unvoiced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are "baked" and "naked" not pronounced the same?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/why-are-baked-and-naked-not-pronounced-the-same) (Read [my answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/267018/106592) in the linked question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [comprehensive answer to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97037/where-does-wicked-get-its-%c9%aad-from) on the English Language & Usage sister site.

Basically, the answer boils down to the fact that the *adjective* "crooked" is not derived from a verb, and so it doesn't follow the typical -ed pronunciation rules for past participles. On the other hand, "to crook" *is* a verb and has a past participle "crooked," as in "He crooked his finger." This word, although spelled the same as the adjective, *is* pronounced as a single syllable, like "looked."

This same situation also arises in some other words like "blessed."