# Pronunciation of "naked"

Tags: pronunciation

Why are there 2 syllables in the word "naked"? Why is the second syllable pronounced "id" and is there only one pronunciation for this word?

Comment: You mean _syllables_! See [this related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34587/why-are-baked-and-naked-not-pronounced-the-same?rq=1)

Comment: I quite like 'syllabuses'. I think I would like Marie-Anne.