# how to pronounce the word 'elementary'?

Tags: pronunciation

In LONGMAN dictionary, the pronunciation of the word *elementary* is /ˌeləˈmentəri/. However, I heard some people pronounced it like /ˌeləˈmentri/. How should I pronounce the word correctly?

Comment: I would pronounce it as the following, eh · luh · men · tr · ee Here is the link to the video that I found it from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJ7ImmpVXWM

Comment: It depends how carefully people are speaking. Almost everybody will give it five syllables when speaking slowly and carefully; but many people elide the fourth syllable in ordinary speech. This is the case for other words where _-ary_ follows a 't', eg _secretary_; and also words formed differently where an unstressed vowel follows a stop consonant, such as _category_ and _allegory_.

Comment: I'd say it's /ɛ/ and not /e/, though. (Also read [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/254188/106592) to a similar question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- /ˌeləˈmen.təri/
- /ˌeləˈmen.tri/

Both of them are correct.

The first one has 5 syllables while the second one has 4. It depends on the dialect of English. Some British and American dialects have lost the weak syllable (second last in 'elementary'—/tə/) so they pronounce it with 4 syllables, but both are equally correct and acceptable.

In English, when a stressed syllable is followed by two (or more) unstressed syllables, the vowel immediately following the stressed syllable is usually dropped in *colloquial/fast speech* (not every accent/dialect and not in every individual's speech). The pronunciation varies from individual to individual. The process is called *[syncope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_(phonology))*. Other examples include: comf**or**table, cam**e**ra, fam**i**ly, av**e**rage etc.

In most dialects, the emboldened vowels have been *syncopated*, however, some dialects have retained them and still pronounce them.

Comment: In upstate New York, many people will pronounce it with initial stress and secondary stress on the penult (EL-em-en-TA-ry). Apparently this is [even more common with *sedimentary*](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1143&context=pwpl). In terms of speech, it is the only distinction I associate with that part of the country.

Comment: @choster I've never heard the version you are discussing here. But a similar version has been brought to my attention and nagging at the back of my mind. A short while ago, a friend noted how I pronounced "elementary" two different ways, one stressing the first syllable /Ele-men-tri/, the other being the more common (ele-mEn-tri). And in my experience, the initial stress version is in the minority in AmE. I wonder if it is really a regional thing. I pronounce it exactly the same as Monica Byrne [here](https://youtu.be/8HfoKd873HY?t=236) who seems to hail from Pennsylvania.